# Can I pull html content with php?

Tags: php, html

I am new to php and am trying to pull content from each webpage.

```
<div id="page_content">
   <p>Each page content</p>
</div>
```

I tried creating a function under global.php:

```
function page_content($page_content) {  
    $page_content = array('id' => 'page_content');  
}
```

Under layout.php I have:

```
<?php echo $page_content; ?>
```

Comment: your function doesn't return anything, and variable is not passed by reference so it doesn't change that

Comment: And `$page_content` it is not a global

Comment: How are you calling this function? As @kmlnvm says, it doesn't do anything at present. Is `'page_content'` a placeholder for an HTML string?

Comment: Is there a way to create a function that can get page content for each webpage?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (your PHP server need to allow url fopen):

```
<?php
      $html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');
      echo $html;
?>
```

Comment: `echo $html` - If OP has more lines below that, will produce a parse error. It's always best to add semi-colons at the end of every ending statement. `echo $html;`

Comment: For     $html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask');     can I create a html div tag with a id or class and have the file_get_contents pull content between the div tags?

Comment: You want jquery selector abilities on you html string?